# FA for when length of $w$ is $4$ or $w$ contains the substring $01$

Tags: finite-automata

I have been trying to create an FA for the language.

$\{w \in \{0, 1\}^∗ , |w|= 4 \vee w \text{ contains the substring }01\}$

I created one that accepts words that contain the substring $01$, but I have a hard time finding a solution for the length part.

This is my attempt so far:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a DFA, or is a NFA enough? If so, you just need to add another part which has 4 transitions until a final state.

Comment: Use the product construction.

Comment: @Nathaniel I need an NFA.

Comment: Thanks, @YuvalFilmus, I took your advice and I was able to produce the union for the two FAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to construct a deterministic automaton for such a language is to use the product construction:

1. Construct an automaton for all words of length $4$.
2. Construct an automaton for all words containing the substring $01$.
3. Use the product construction to construct an automaton for the union.

If you are allowed to use a nondeterministic automaton, then you can replace the product automaton with a "union automaton", that is, add a new initial state and connect to the the initial states of the two automata with $\epsilon$ transitions.